# Problems with adding links to an itens in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to add links to some divs in Wordpress, so I tried writting some JS code for it. But I keep getting the following error " Uncaught TypeError: addId.setAttribute is not a function "

I'll leave the code down bellow. Thank you everyone for the help

```js
var addId = document.getElementsByClassName("elementor-repeater-item-d7362c2");

addId.setAttribute('id', "item");


ogElement = document.getElementByid("item").innerHTML;
addLink = "<a href='https://www.vivendus.com.br/product-category/colar/'>" + ogElement + "</a>";
document.getElementByid("test").innerHTML = addLink;
```

```css
.elementor-repeater-item-d7362c2 {
  color:#ccff00;
  font-size:2em;
}
```

```html
<div class ='elementor-repeater-item-d7362c2'> test <div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements, not an element. You should specify which element you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

```
var addId = document.getElementsByClassName("elementor-repeater-item-d7362c2");
```

This will return an array or a list if i remember right, you need to get it by id or iterate on addId and setAttribute on each element !

Comment: The div doesnt have an id and i can't  acesse the original code to add one. How can  I add an id to each element ?

Comment: So make a while loop or access directly to the element you need with addId[0] (first element)